# Getting ga:socialNetwork dimension in BigQuery Export

Tags: google-analytics, social-networking, google-bigquery

I'm trying to retrieve site referral data from social networks via BigQuery Export.

I've gotten the referral path from such sites, but what I cannot seem to find is the neatly categorized field that is available in Google Analytics.

i.e. **ga:socialNetwork**

Anyone know where to find this data?

So far, I've looked here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

(and, in our data, of course)

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the `ga:socialNetwork` dimension isn't currently available via BigQuery Export, as you mentioned, you can get the referral path using `trafficSource.source`.

You can see the difference between these two fields by [running this query](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?dimensions=ga%253AsocialNetwork%252C%2520ga%253Asource&metrics=ga%253Asessions&filters=ga%253AsocialNetwork!%253D(not%2520set)&sort=-ga%253Asessions&start-date=2014-10-31&end-date=2014-11-14&max-results=50) (against the Core Reporting API, which has both fields). You can then use the result as a lookup table for your data.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested here was my solution, based on Andy's answer:

SELECT

```
Week, 
IF (SocialNetwork IS NULL, Medium, "social" ) AS Medium,
Referral_URL,
SocialNetwork,
Total_Sessions,
Avg_Time_On_Site_in_Mins,
Avg_Session_Page_Depth,
Bounce_Rate,
```

FROM  (

```
    SELECT

      Week, 
      Medium,
      Referral_HostName,
      Referral_URL,
      SocialNetworks.socialNetwork AS SocialNetwork,
      Total_Sessions,
      Avg_Time_On_Site_in_Mins,
      Avg_Session_Page_Depth,
      Bounce_Rate,


    FROM

    [zzzzzzz.ga_sessions_20141223] AS All_Sessions

    LEFT JOIN EACH [GA_API.SocialNetworks] AS SocialNetworks
    ON ALL_Sessions.Referral_HostName = SocialNetworks.Source


    GROUP EACH BY Week, Medium, Full_URL, Referral_HostName, Referral_URL, SocialNetwork, Total_Sessions, Avg_Time_On_Site_in_Mins, Avg_Session_Page_Depth, Bounce_Rate,
    ORDER BY Total_Sessions DESC )
```

GROUP EACH BY Week, Medium, Full_URL, Referral_URL, SocialNetwork, Total_Sessions, Avg_Time_On_Site_in_Mins, Avg_Session_Page_Depth, Bounce_Rate,
 ORDER BY Total_Sessions DESC;

Answer (score 0):

This is now available in BigQuery Export with the field name `hits.social.socialNetwork`.

The detailed documentation is here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

Following this documentation I ran a sample query which worked fine

```
SELECT
  COUNT(totals.visits),
  hits.social.socialNetwork
FROM
  [project:dataset.ga_sessions_20161101]
GROUP BY
  hits.social.socialNetwork
ORDER BY
  1 DESC
```